# Target a page with query

Tags: query, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I have those 2 pages that are created from a plugin (see the plugin https://zombify.px-lab.com/frontend-page/, just login and choose a post type, check the url):

1. https://www.domain.com/post-create-page/?type=story
2. https://www.domain.com/post-create-page/?type=trivia

The plugin is making use of custom post type.
I have been trying to target them

```php
if (is_page ('post-create-page') && ... )
```

with `get_query_var` by trying to pass the `$qvars` to `add_filter( 'query_vars'` but I am not sure how to do that.

Could some one help me how i could target those 2 pages?
Thank you

Comment: which plugin created these pages? When you say _page_ do you mean a post of type page listed in the pages section of the admin UI, or or do you mean a webpage as in something shown at a URL in the browser? You will need to provide a lot more information ( and be very specific and exact with your wording, be pedantic and very precise to avoid confusion and ambiguity ). This is important as there are multiple things that could be implementing that page, e.g. rewrite rules, page templates, etc and without knowing which it is people can't help

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you. I have updated with more info my question. i hope this helps

Comment: the link you added isn't a plugin, it looks like a demo site of what you're working on, but there is no code and I can't see the name of the plugin or where it came from or any clues as to how the page is built, I'd suggest you ask the authors as 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here. Is Zombify the product you bought and px-lab.com the vendors/authors?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked at the source code and found $_GET as a solution to target them.

```
$type = isset($_GET["type"]) ? $_GET["type"] : 'story';


if( is_page('post-create-page') && $type=='story' ) { ....} elseif ( is_page('post-create-page') && $type=='openlist' ) {.....}
```